# Is there "0b" or something similar to represent a binary number in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I know that `0x` is a prefix for hexadecimal numbers in Javascript. For example, `0xFF` stands for the number 255.

Is there something similar for binary numbers ? I would expect `0b1111` to represent the number `15`, but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why would you need binary literals in Javascript? The high-level nature of Javascript means that it usually doesn't need to interact with low-level constructs that would require binary literals.

Comment: Because this way the code will be more readable. My implementation is based on some Specification which uses binary numbers.

Comment: using node js for robotics is a good example of where binary may be required

Comment: You may consider using [_numeric separators_](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator) for better readability. `0b0111_0_1_0_1`.

Comment: If you are using any code that explore all posible options a simulation could be run you will need binary values. As a sort of binary table.

Comment: Another use case (since it's a valid question that others may ask):

If you want to store a structure containing the results of combinations of independent binary choices, naming each one becomes unwieldy, making the option of encoding these choices in a binary representation a good one, at lease IMO (not to mention this is exactly how such choices are encoded in binary data / embedded systems).

Answer (score 286, accepted):

**Update:**

Newer versions of JavaScript -- specifically ECMAScript 6 -- have added support for binary (prefix `0b`), octal (prefix `0o`) and hexadecimal (prefix: `0x`) numeric literals:

```
var bin = 0b1111;    // bin will be set to 15
var oct = 0o17;      // oct will be set to 15
var oxx = 017;       // oxx will be set to 15
var hex = 0xF;       // hex will be set to 15
// note: bB oO xX are all valid
```

This feature is already available in Firefox and Chrome. It's not currently supported in IE, but apparently will be when Spartan arrives.

*(Thanks to [Semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631952/semicolon)'s comment and [urish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803145/is-there-0b-or-something-similar-to-represent-a-binary-number-in-javascript/25613516#25613516) for pointing this out.)*

**Original Answer:**

No, there isn't an equivalent for binary numbers. JavaScript only supports numeric literals in decimal (no prefix), hexadecimal (prefix `0x`) and octal (prefix `0`) formats.

One possible alternative is to pass a binary string to the `parseInt` method along with the radix:

```
var foo = parseInt('1111', 2);    // foo will be set to 15
```

Comment: @MishaMoroshko I agree, but few languages have `0b` support.

Comment: Technically, JavaScript doesn't feature octal notation, although most (all?) browsers support it. It's explicitly disallowed in strict mode.

Comment: Note that internally in JavaScript, every number is a 64bit float, there is no such thing as integer. Thus with huge numbers, you loose accuracy. The biggest accurate "integer" is 2^53, or 9007199254740992.

Comment: There are integers, since integer is a mathematics term, there is no `int type` nor `integer type`, so all integers are stored as floats.

Comment: Note that it is important to remember that JavaScript does NOT support octal by default because `"030" * 100 = 3000` whereas `030 * 100 = 2400`. That can be surprising to some.

Comment: JavaScript numbers are not always stored as floats. Bitwise operators will convert the number to a signed 32 bit integer.

Comment: This answer was true at the time, but it could use an update. As urish points out in his answer below, literals for binary and octal numbers (octals are now written "0o1") are in ES6. They've already landed in Firefox, Chrome, and even the preview of the new IE (Spartan).

Comment: concat a binary prefix to convert to 10-base number: `Number('0b' + '1000101011')`

Comment: @Alexis Wilke this is more of a notation trap for C/C++ people, explicitly specifying the 0o.. prefix will get you by.

Comment: This is all very well for numerics, but what about arrays of char or non-terminated strings? We should not have to be making database calls to unhex into binary.

Comment: @mckenzm You may want to test with JavaScript. "030" and 030 do not come out the same...

Comment: As an addition, 13th added numeric seperators as well. `0b0010_0010_1101`

Comment: [0b notation is currently supported in nearly all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=0b)

Comment: "0"-prefixed octal literals are deprecated; use the "0o" prefix instead

Comment: What is oxx? Seems like octal, but, why would they have two ways of writing octal?

Answer (score 37):

In ECMASCript 6 this will be supported as a part of the language, i.e. `0b1111 === 15` is true. You can also use an uppercase B (e.g. `0B1111`).

Look for `NumericLiterals` in the [ES6 Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-literals-numeric-literals).

Answer (score 27):

If your primary concern is display rather than coding, there's a built-in conversion system you can use:

```
var num = 255;
document.writeln(num.toString(16)); // Outputs: "ff"
document.writeln(num.toString(8)); // Outputs: "377"
document.writeln(num.toString(2)); // Outputs: "11111111"
```

Ref: [MDN on `Number.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString#description)

Answer (score 24):

I know that people says that extending the prototypes is not a good idea, but been your script...

I do it this way:

```
Object.defineProperty(
    Number.prototype, 'b', {
        set:function(){
            return false;
        },

        get:function(){
            return parseInt(this, 2);
        }
    }
);


100..b       // returns 4
11111111..b  // returns 511
10..b+1      // returns 3

// and so on
```

Comment: This is cool! 8-) Note that `ParseInt("101", 2)` could be the actual answer!

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know it is not possible to use a binary denoter in Javascript. I have three solutions for you, all of which have their issues. I think alternative 3 is the most "good looking" for readability, and it is possibly much faster than the rest - except for it's initial run time cost. The problem is it only supports values up to 255.

Alternative 1: `"00001111".b()`

```
String.prototype.b = function() { return parseInt(this,2); }
```

Alternative 2: `b("00001111")`

```
function b(i) { if(typeof i=='string') return parseInt(i,2); throw "Expects string"; }
```

Alternative 3: `b00001111`

This version allows you to type either 8 digit binary `b00000000`, 4 digit `b0000` and variable digits `b0`. That is `b01` is illegal, you have to use `b0001` or `b1`.

```
String.prototype.lpad = function(padString, length) {
    var str = this;
    while (str.length < length)
        str = padString + str;
    return str;
}
for(var i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    window['b' + i.toString(2)] = window['b' + i.toString(2).lpad('0', 8)] = window['b' + i.toString(2).lpad('0', 4)] = i;
```

Answer (score 6):

May be this will usefull:

```
var bin = 1111;
var dec = parseInt(bin, 2);
// 15
```

Comment: Cute, if a bit weird. But that's JavaScript for you. `bin` is assigned a number that looks like it's in binary, but is actually being parsed base 10. The `parseInt` function expects a string as the first arg, so it turns it into "1111" (base 10 representation), then re-parses it as if it were base 2.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can use parseInt and optionally omit the quotes.

```
parseInt(110, 2); // this is 6 
parseInt("110", 2); // this is also 6
```

The only disadvantage of omitting the quotes is that, for very large numbers, you will overflow faster:

```
parseInt(10000000000000000000000, 2); // this gives 1
parseInt("10000000000000000000000", 2); // this gives 4194304
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this does not actually answer the asked Q (which was already answered several times) as is, however I suggest that you (or others interested in this subject) consider the fact that the most readable & backwards/future/cross browser-compatible way would be to just use the hex representation.

From the phrasing of the Q it would seem that you are only talking about using binary literals in your code and not processing of binary representations of numeric values (for which parstInt is the way to go).

I doubt that there are many programmers that need to handle binary numbers that are not familiar with the mapping of 0-F to 0000-1111.
so basically make groups of four and use hex notation.

so instead of writing 101000000010 you would use 0xA02 which has exactly the same meaning and is far more readable and less less likely to have errors.

Just consider readability, Try comparing which of those is bigger:
10001000000010010  or 1001000000010010

and what if I write them like this:
0x11012 or 0x9012

Answer (score 1):

Convert binary strings to numbers and visa-versa.

```
var b = function(n) {
    if(typeof n === 'string')
        return parseInt(n, 2);
    else if (typeof n === 'number')
        return n.toString(2);
    throw "unknown input";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Number() function works...

```js
// using Number() 
var bin = Number('0b1111');    // bin will be set to 15
var oct = Number('0o17');      // oct will be set to 15
var oxx = Number('0xF');       // hex will be set to 15

// making function convTo
const convTo = (prefix,n) => {
  return Number(`${prefix}${n}`) //Here put prefix 0b, 0x and num
}

console.log(bin)
console.log(oct)
console.log(oxx)

// Using convTo function
console.log(convTo('0b',1111))
```