# How do I pass a binary literal to JavaScript eval?

Tags: java, javascript, binary, eval, literals

**Before I start, please don't tell me not to use `eval`; I know the input is perfectly sanitary, so it's safe, fast, and easy.**

I'm using a JavaScript engine to power a calculator I've written in Java. To do this, I simply concatonate input into a string and pass it to JavaScript. For instance, clicking the buttons `1`, `+`, and `5` results in building the String `"1+5"`. I got this working for hexadecimal, too, by putting `0x` before the letters, so `A`, `+`, and `8` gives me `"0xA+8`. My problem comes from programming its binary mode. I tried passing it `0b1101+0b10` (which is how Java does binary literals), but it just throws an error. **How do I handle binary literals in JavaScript?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2803145/34397

Comment: There are MANY reasons to avoid `eval` that have nothing to do with script injection or sanitizing inputs. For one thing, it's orders of magnitude slower. For another thing, `eval` uses weird scoping rules that make it very, very easy to get subtle bugs in your code.

Comment: @JustinMorgan: You are correct. But only correct for 99.9% of cases. There is always the 0.1% freak-of-nature cases that necessitates the use of bad practice; despite the risk and maintainability problems.

Comment: @Phil I feel like mine was one. Where I am given a string like "2+8*26/0.61-0xF3" and have to give the numerical result. It's much easier to just have the JS engine evaluate it than to parse it and deal with the math myself.

Comment: The fact that you use Java to run your calculator is not important to the question. Please remove the Java tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** As of ES2015, JavaScript supports binary `Number` literals:

```js
console.log(0b1101+0b10) // 15 (in decimal)
```

Alternatively, you can use a string, and use [`Number.parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt) with a base of 2:

```js
var a = parseInt('1101', 2) // Note base 2!
var b = parseInt('0010', 2) // Note base 2!
console.log(a+b) // 15 (in decimal)
```

For displaying numbers in different bases, [`Number#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) also accepts a base:

```js
(15).toString(2) // 1111
```

Note: If passing user input directly to `eval()`, use a regex to ensure the input only contains numbers and the operators you expect (`+`, `-`, etc).

Comment: As I said; it's not user input. That's why I didn't want anypony to talk about eval. This is input from a compiled Java program which I have pre-programmed and formatted myself, interpreted by the internal Java JavaScript engine.