# What is the best way to store very large binary numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, binary, biginteger, bitarray

I'm currently learning JavaScript and I'm very surprised there is not built-in way to work with binary numbers. I have to work with integers up to 2^4096 so I just can't use JS integers for my calculus.

My first thought was to use Arrays of 1 and 0. But that's not satisfying since a simple multiplication by 2 requires to shift the whole table.

So how can I work efficiently with binary numbers in JavaScript ?

I'd like not to use any library. I'm interested in how it works, not in using other's abstraction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a bignum library for JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/is-there-a-bignum-library-for-javascript)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder These are available for integers, but integers can't exceed 2^64 as far as I know

Comment: @Barmar I'm not looking for a library.

Comment: If you want to know how it works, read the source of the library.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard: Actually it's `2^32` when you're dealing with the bitwise operators. Sorry, I misread your question.

Comment: I'll bet it uses an array of 32- or 64-bit integers, rather than an array of 1's and 0's.

Comment: Maybe [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803145/is-there-0b-or-something-similar-to-represent-a-binary-number-in-javascript) with similar issue can help you?

Comment: *"I'm very surprised there is not built-in way to work with binary numbers"* There **is**. There's just no built-in way to work with binary numbers larger than 32-bits, which isn't uncommon (and particularly wasn't uncommon when JavaScript was created).

Comment: How do you mean "work with"? It would improve the question if you listed the kinds of operations do you need to perform.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Basically additions, multiplications, divisions, modulus, power and comparisons. That's for cryptographic means. I read bits of code from the jsbn library but it's not very well documented. Maybe the Biginteger library would be better to read.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard: To improve your (very interesting) question, use the "edit" link under the question rather than comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have any biginteger type, so you would need to use an array to hold that much information.

An array of 0 and 1 values would make it easy to implement functions for it, but not very efficient.

A regular number in Javascript is a double precision floating point number, so it can hold 52 bits of numeric information [(ref)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), but you would use slightly less to be far away from any rounding errors, for example 48 bits.

The bitwise operators in Javascript work with 32 bit integers, i.e. a double is converted to a 32 bit integer when used with a bitwise operator. If you want to use the bitwise operators on the data, you could choose to store 32 bits per item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript only supports 53 bit integers.

The best way to store "big integers" is to convert them to strings on server side. And in case you want to manipulate them I would suggest to look at this library https://github.com/rauschma/strint