# how to use this javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have found a javascript on github given here: https://gist.github.com/faisalman/4213592

```
(function(){
 var convertBase = function (num) {
    this.from = function (baseFrom) {
        this.to = function (baseTo) {
            return parseInt(num, baseFrom).toString(baseTo);
        };
        return this;
    };
    return this;
};

// binary to decimal
this.bin2dec = function (num) {
    return convertBase(num).from(2).to(10);
};

// binary to hexadecimal
this.bin2hex = function (num) {
    return convertBase(num).from(2).to(16);
};

// decimal to binary
this.dec2bin = function (num) {
    return convertBase(num).from(10).to(2);
};

// decimal to hexadecimal
this.dec2hex = function (num) {
    return convertBase(num).from(10).to(16);
};

// hexadecimal to binary
this.hex2bin = function (num) {
    return convertBase(num).from(16).to(2);
};

// hexadecimal to decimal
this.hex2dec = function (num) {
    return convertBase(num).from(16).to(10);
};

return this;        
})();
```

and in html part i am trying to convert input given to binary to hexa by using bin2hex function.I want that if a user inputs a binary value text in textarea given, by clicking the button it gets converted to hexadecimal value.

nothing seem to happen . what's wrong i am doing here? Pardon me if i seem to be novice. I have already spent hours on this.here is jsfiddle so far. http://jsfiddle.net/7BRwL/

Comment: A form does not have a value. Perhaps you mean "this.tal.value=bin2hex(this.form.tal.value)"

Comment: if the function is returning values at the end, what other methods can i adopt here,

Comment: All those calls to `convertBase` appear to be missing `new` in front. Otherwise 2 global functions `from` and `to` will keep getting clobbered on every invocation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/N2j8N/ works for me using the comment above

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the returned value.

I copied your onclick-attribute to a function. This reads the current input, converts it and writes the result into the textarea.

```
document.querySelector('input').onclick = function() {
    var input = document.querySelector('textarea#ta1');
    input.value = bin2hex(input.value);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7BRwL/6/

So the binary `0101010` converts correct to hexadecimal `2A`.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet from Github is an **IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)**, which means it executes immediately. The function returns itself, but because you haven't assigned it to a variable, it returns itself to the global scope (`window.bin2hex()` or just `bin2hex()`).

So you can simply assign the function to a variable if you like:

```
var convert = (function(){ ... })();
convert.bin2hex(100011101); // will return the hexadecimal equivalent
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7BRwL/5/

In your case, the textarea's id is the only error though, and can be corrected simply like this:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('ta1').value=bin2hex(document.getElementById('ta1').value)
```

Comment: How does `convert === window` help this cause?

Comment: @Bergi it doesn't, I'm just providing extra background info on how IIFE's can be and are often used, as I understood from the question that the asker might not be aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the button in the fiddle to:

```
<input onclick="convert.ta1.value=bin2hex(convert.ta1.value)" type="button" value="convert"/>
```

You were using the wrong name for the textarea field. And the value to be converted has to be passed as an argument to the function.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/7BRwL/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to have a user have their text converted and displayed, here is an example I have.

[image]

```
<body>
<script>
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803145/is-there-0b-or-something-similar-to-represent-a-binary-number-in-javascript
function showConvert(){
var userText = document.getElementById('text1').value;
document.getElementById('text2').value = Number(userText).toString(2);
document.getElementById('text3').value = Number(userText).toString(16);
}
</script>

<form> 
<center>
<input id="text1" type="text" value = "47"><br>
<input id="submit1" type="button" value="Convert" onClick="showConvert();"><br>
<input id="text2" type="text"><br>
<input id="text3" type="text"><br>
</form>
</body>
```