# JavaScript encrypt in sha512 and obtain result in raw binary data like PHP hash()

Tags: javascript, symfony, hash

As I said in the title I need to reproduce this PHP function (in JavaScript):

```php
hash("sha512", "string", true);
```

The tricky part if for the true at the end which means:

> When set to TRUE, outputs raw binary data. FALSE outputs lowercase
> hexits.

This can be important too if I need to create something by myself and if I should take care of the endian:

> The tiger algorithm now uses big-endian byte ordering.

Reference: [php.net - hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)

**EDIT**: After some tests and research here is the function I need to reproduce in JavaScript:

```php
hex2bin("string");
```

Actually witch CryptoJS I'm able to obtain the result in hexa. I don't know exactly how to obtain it in row binary data (hex2bin equivalent).

I found that with NodeJS and the library crypto we can do that easily but I don't use NodeJS. I need to obtain the same result in classic JavaScript (or jQuery or any other lib which will work).

My goal is to send to a Symfony's WSSE protocol a password that will match the one in database (passwordDigest).

Here is the PHP code I need to reproduce:

```php
public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
    {

        // ... Some check code for data

        $salted = $this->mergePasswordAndSalt($raw, $salt); // Just do $raw."{".$salt."}";
        $digest = hash($this->algorithm, $salted, true);

        // "stretch" hash
        for ($i = 1; $i < $this->iterations; $i++) {
            $digest = hash($this->algorithm, $digest.$salted, true);
        }

        return $this->encodeHashAsBase64 ? base64_encode($digest) :
bin2hex($digest);
    }
```

And here is the code in JavaScript I actually have:

```js
WSSE.encodePassword = function(password, salt) {
    try {
        var salted = WSSE.mergePasswordAndSalt(password, salt);
        var digest = CryptoJS.SHA512(salted).toString();

        for (i = 1; i < 5000; i++) {
            digest = CryptoJS.SHA512(digest + salted).toString();
        }

        return WSSE.base64_encode(digest);
    } catch(err) {
        Log.e("WSSE", err.message);
        return null;
    }
};
```

The problem with this code is that the digest variable always contains data in hexa, not in raw binary data.

An idea, code, or lib everyone?

Comment: It's better to keep the hex and convert it to binary on your server, since binary data is pretty complicated to deal with in javascript, especially if you're sending requests to a server with it. Take a look at this question about binary data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803145/is-there-0b-or-something-similar-to-represent-a-binary-number-in-javascript

Comment: I would like to do it but as there is a loop of 5000 iteration in which the binary raw output is concatenate with the salted I don't think it will work.

Comment: So you need `digest` to be binary? Javascript treats all number-systems as base10 numbers, for example: console.log(0xff) -> 255, check the question I linked

Comment: Yes I need it to be raw binary. I think there is a difference between binary and raw binary. When I print the result in PHP I obtain funny ASCII characters, I want to have the same and not stuffs like 00100100 00110101 ...
But your first idea could work. I try to see if I can obtain binary raw output from the result of the first sha512()

Comment: After some tests I succeed to obtain raw binary data from Hexa string on PHP with the function: hex2bin();
http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php

Now I try to find if there is a JavaScript equivalent of this hex2bin() PHP function.

Comment: Cool :) There might be, but binary is not exactly javascripts strength, haha

Comment: Yeah I saw that thank to your link ! I always try to figure out how to reproduce hex2bin(); PHP function but if I can't it's not a big deal, I can do that in the PHP part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for it, based on a WSSE Implementation for EmberJS : https://github.com/Gerfaut/ember-simple-wsse-auth

Precisly in https://github.com/Gerfaut/ember-simple-wsse-auth/blob/master/packages/ember-simple-wsse-auth/lib/core.js

```
Ember.SimpleWsseAuth.EncodePassword = function(password, salt) {
    var salted = password + '{' + salt + '}';
    var passwordEncoded = CryptoJS.SHA512(salted);
    for(var i = 1; i < this.passwordEncodingIterations; i++) { //TODO use webworker
        passwordEncoded = CryptoJS.SHA512(passwordEncoded.concat(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(salted)));
    }
    return this.passwordEncodingAsBase64 ? passwordEncoded.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64) : passwordEncoded;
};
```

Your encodePassword function become

```
WSSE.encodePassword = function(password, salt) {
    try {
        var salted = WSSE.mergePasswordAndSalt(password, salt);
        var digest = CryptoJS.SHA512(salted);

        for (i = 1; i < 5000; i++) {
            digest = CryptoJS.SHA512(digest.concat(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(salted)));
        }    

        return WSSE.base64_encode(digest);
    } catch(err) {
        Log.e("WSSE", err.message);
        return null;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

using http://movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha512.html you obtain the same output as using the function

```
hash('sha512', 'puma');
```

That is an excellent solution from [Chris Veness](https://github.com/chrisveness)