# javascript returns 9 for 0011

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have a function where I passes the value dynamically

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="searchError(0011)">0011</a>
```

In javascript am just passing this value and it returns me 9

JS

```
function searchError(s){
        alert(s);           
}
```

Need help  to understand why ?

I fixed it by quoting the value like

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="searchError('0011')">0011</a>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dngm0d1e/)

Comment: Possibly interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803145/is-there-0b-or-something-similar-to-represent-a-binary-number-in-javascript Top answer has an interesting comment: `Technically, JavaScript doesn't feature octal notation, although most (all?) browsers support it. It's explicitly disallowed in strict mode.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0011` is an [octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) since it has a leftmost `0` so its equal to  0 x 8<sup>2</sup> + 1 x 8<sup>1</sup> + 1 x 8<sup>0</sup> = 9. Originally the value was interpreted as a numeric. Enclosing it in quotes caused it to be treated as a String literal.