# Why would one use binary integer literals instead of integers or floats in python?

Tags: python, binary

Shouldn't we keep code as simple and easy to understand as possible? What are the advantages of binary over floats and integers in python and is it possible to create floats with binary. Also, when would you use it?

Comment: ...what? Could you provide examples of what you mean? Do you mean *"binary [integer literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals)"*, like `0b1010`?

Comment: Why would you drive a bike instead of a car?

Comment: Bitmasks & their manipulations can be a lot clearer in binary notation than in integer or floating point notation.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you mean:

> Why does Python have binary [integer literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals)?

e.g. allowing  `0b1010` as well as `10`, then the answer is that sometimes that *is* the most *"simple and easy to understand"* approach to writing code.

For example, the number I use above could be a bitmask, indicating the combination of the second and fourth options. Which is clearer:

```
a = 0b0001
b = 0b0010
c = 0b0100
d = 0b1000

x = 0b1010
```

or:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 4
d = 8

x = 10
```

*(In practice you'd just use `x = a | c` and e.g. [`re`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/sre_constants.py#l164) actually uses decimal literals for the flags, but I needed an example and note that the bitwise operations on integers are also easier to understand in binary notation.)*

See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803145/is-there-0b-or-something-similar-to-represent-a-binary-number-in-javascript#comment2845637_2803145) for another reason, sometimes binary is part of the language of the domain you're working in:

> Because this way the code will be more readable. My implementation is
>   based on some Specification which uses binary numbers. –  Misha
>   Moroshko *May 11 '10 at 0:36*

And no, there is no binary [floating point literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals) in Python.