# Why does a JavaScript function automatically convert a binary number when I pass it as an argument?

Tags: javascript

I guess I can format it back. I'm just interested in why it's happening.

```
function test(d){
 console.log(d) // 151028224
}
console.log(test(00001100101000))
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/2803188/1563833 regarding how to write binary numbers.

Comment: As a general rule in all programming languages: all numbers are stored in binary, and, by default, displayed as decimal. The computer does not bother to track what format was used to write the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, any number literally written with a zero at the beginning is considered as **octal** (base 8) number representation, and then, when you show back any number with `console.log`, it is written as its base 10 representation.

```js
console.log(05)
console.log(06)
console.log(07)
console.log(010)
console.log(011)
```

It's recommended to avoid this in code, because it can lead to confusions :

if the number contains the digits 8 or 9, it cannot be a base-8 number, and thus treated as base 10 !

```js
console.log(05)
console.log(06)
console.log(07)
console.log(08) // Yiiik !
console.log(09) // Yiiik !
console.log(010)
console.log(011)
```

Answer (score 4):

The function has nothing to do with it.

The JavaScript compiler converts your number literal into a Number when it compiles the source code.

Since [the number starts with a `0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Octal_numbers), it is treated as octal instead of decimal.